# azure proxy call and same back end function call behaving differently

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-function-app-proxy

i am facing an issue with azure proxy call.

Created a azure function app.
Created a basic get function and sending response body in json format back.
response body example{url: "https://www.google.com"}

If i configure direct function endpoint in one of my company application everything working fine able launch response url coming from azure function call.

I created proxy for the same get function and configured proxy end point in my application.Now application is failing to launch response url.(but back end same function is hitting and logs created no error in logs and ended with status 200)

Unfortunately i don't have control on application code to verify what exact cause in response.

I verified azure function call and proxy call from postman both are giving same response body. I don't know why it is failing in my application
i didn't understand.

One more point i verified response headers in postman in both cases

**For function app end point call response headers:**
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Wed, 09 Jan 2019 12:39:23 GMT
server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
transfer-encoding →chunked
x-powered-by →ASP.NET

**For proxy endpoint call response headers:**
content-encoding →gzip
content-length →208
content-type →application/json; charset=utf-8
date →Wed, 09 Jan 2019 12:41:16 GMT
server →Microsoft-IIS/10.0
vary →Accept-Encoding
x-powered-by →ASP.NET, ASP.NET

is gzip encoding creating problem in proxy call. How to disable it in azure proxy.

my application should able to launch even if i use proxy end point.

Comment: Could you share more details on what kind of application it is? If its a browser based application, you will have to setup CORS in your function app for the calls to succeed.